# How to do run-length encoding without creating sublists?

Tags: python, list, matrix, encoding, python-itertools

Thanking you for your help, I'd like to know how to make a function that does run-length encoding of a list, but doesn't create sublists. The reason is that each list represents a row of a two-dimensional list. In this way when I go to decode everything I will be able to do it line by line, having kept the lines of the original list.
If possible, modify the code that I enclose, as it does a run-length encoding by writing the numbers of the repeated values, not writing the numbers of the values that are present only once.

```
from itertools import groupby
def modified_encode(alist):
        def ctr_ele(el):
            if len(el)>1:
                return [len(el), el[0]]
            else:
                return el[0]
        return [ctr_ele(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(alist)]
```

I'll explain. Here is an example using the function posted here:

```
wall = 'wall'
concrete = 'concrete'
>>> map=[wall, wall, concrete, concrete]
>>> modified_encode(map)
[[2, 'wall'], [2, 'concrete']]
```

The result I would like instead is this:

```
[2, 'wall', 2, 'concrete']
```

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: I don't understand problem. Maybe show example data and expected result.

Comment: don't put code directly after `:` (but move to next line) because this make code unreadable.

Comment: I'll explain. Here is an example using the function posted here:
```
wall = 'wall'
concrete = 'concrete'
>>> map=[wall, wall, concrete, concrete]
>>> modified_encode(map)
[[2, 'wall'], [2, 'concrete']]
```

The result I would like instead is this:
```
[2, 'wall', 2, 'concrete']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always return `list` - even for single item `[ el[0] ]` - and then you can use fact that you can add lists:

`[2,'wall'] + [2,'concrete'] + ['single']` gives `[2,'wall',2,'concrete','single']`

You may even use `sum(..., [])` for this.

```
from itertools import groupby

def modified_encode(alist):
    def ctr_ele(el):
        if len(el)>1:
            return [len(el), el[0]]
        else:
            return [ el[0] ]   # <--- return list with single element
    
    result = (ctr_ele(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(alist))
    flatten = sum(result , [])  # <--- add all lists to `[]`

    return flatten

data = ['wall', 'wall', 'concrete', 'concrete', 'single']

modified_encode(data)
```

Result:

```
[2, 'wall', 2, 'concrete', 'single']
```

---

**EDIT:**

Or you could write it in different way - without `ctr_ele` - and use `append()`

```
from itertools import groupby

def modified_encode(alist):
    result = []
    
    for key, group in groupby(alist):
        el = list(group)
        if len(el) > 1:
            result.append(len(el))
        result.append(el[0])
        
    return result

data = ['wall', 'wall', 'concrete', 'concrete', 'single']

modified_encode(data)
```